# When to use catch and when to use throws in the exception handling

Tags: java, exception

**The question is not about exception handling syntax,** but it is all about which is the right place to write catch block for an exception in its journey over methods through propagation.

```java
public boolean validateUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    boolean result = false;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE   USERNAME=? AND PASSWORD=?");
    pstmt.setString(1, username);
    pstmt.setString(2, password);
    result = pstmt.executeQuery().next();
    conn.close();
    return result;
}
```

Assume `method1()` called `method2()` and `method2()` called above method. In the above method if I handle the exception, I have to return a value. Let's assume that I have returned `false` after catch block, `method2()` misunderstands like the username or password is wrong.

If I am not handling, `method2()` will not receive any value and it's catch block will execute and the same problem would occur in `method1()`.

**Now can you define where can I effectively handle the exception?**

Comment: Can you please clarify your question >?

Comment: this is a very broad and opinion based question - exception handling depends on your style and what you are used to.

Comment: I think the correct answer here is probably *sparingly*. Exceptions should be used for exceptional things, and you should probably catch it wherever it's possible to recover. If it isn't possible to recover then you should probably allow it to propagate.

Comment: It's more than style but it is a subjective question. Maybe better for Programmers.SE?

Comment: Your new code isn't valid in any case. If there's an exception it can leak a Connection, a PreparedStatement, and a ResultSet.

Answer (score 3):

You should `catch` an exception only if you can reasonably recover from the error condition.  In every other case, you should propagate it up to your caller and hope that he might be able to handle it in a meaningful way.  If nobody up the call stack will be able to handle it, termination of the application is probably the correct thing to happen.

Suppose you are writing a graphical user interface with icons.  You have one method

```java
Icon loadIcon(String filename) throws IOException;
```

that loads the icon's image from a disk file.  If this I/O operation fails, there is no obvious way `loadIcon` could recover from that error.  It is probably best to let the exception propagate.

Somewhere else, you have another method

```java
void buildGUI();
```

that populates the user interface.  It will make use of `loadIcon` to get icons for the various buttons based on the currently selected icon theme.  If loading one icon fails, this would be a poor reason to crash the whole GUI building process.  Here, we should probably catch the exception and try using a fallback icon or display an empty button.  This will allow the user to still use the application and perhaps realize that some icons are missing and thus go and fix their installation.

Answer (score 0):

If the *documented purpose* of method X is to call method Y which can throw `SomeCheckedException`, and the only way in which `SomeCheckedException` can get thrown from method X are those that X's caller will expect, then it would be reasonable for X to be declared as `throws SomeCheckedException` and simply let exceptions thrown by Y propagate through to X's caller.  That's not a terribly common situation, however.

If the purpose of X is to perform some operation, and although it happens to use method Y for the purpose, nothing in X's documentation specifies that it will call a method which throws `SomeCheckedException`, then the fact that X calls a method which might throw `SomeCheckedException` should be considered an implementation detail; it should not be exposed to the caller.  In that case, if Y throws a `SomeCheckedException`, X should catch it, wrap it, and rethrow it as something that will make sense to X's caller.

Note that if X simply declares `throws SomeCheckedException`, there will be no reliable way for X's caller to distinguish between a `SomeCheckedException` which was thrown for reasons it expects, from one which was thrown by a method call that whose failure wasn't anticipated.  By contrast, if calls to methods which X expects might throw `SomeCheckedException` are wrapped with try/catch/throw blocks that rethrow as a type that the caller is expecting, but those which X does not expect to ever actually throw that exception are wrapped in try/catch/throw blocks that throw an "unexpected exception" exception, then those situations will be recognizable as distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the exception to your benefit, to short-circuit and fail fast when something goes wrong, so that once a problem surfaces your code isn't blundering onward trying to execute when it's no longer relevant.

In your example, you need the connection, the prepared statement, and the resultset. The exceptions thrown by these are mostly nonrecoverable; if anything is wrong (the grammar of the SQL is bad, or the result set column names are incorrect, or the database goes down, or the connection times out, etc.) while getting or using any one of these, you're done.

Catching the exception within the method would be bad, because you have things outside of that method that are depending on getting a result from that method, and if the query fails there's no point proceeding. And the error-checking gets entangled with the happy-path business logic, making the code harder to read.

You need to let the exception be thrown until it reaches a point where it is outside of the whole business operation you are trying to execute.

So the general idea is to identify units of work, where if anything goes wrong the whole thing has to be abandoned. Then outside that unit of work you can put a handler that catches the exception and does whatever logging, notification, etc. that you need.

Take a unit test framework, for instance, like JUnit or TestNG. Each method of a testcase object gets executed, and if anything is thrown from it then the framework calling the method catches it, figures out whether it was expected, saves the results for display to the user, and goes on.

Likewise in a web application, each HTTP request typically is a unit of work, and any exception that gets thrown doesn't get caught until it reaches a global handler that catches anything thrown from the controller layer.

For Swing applications you can implement an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=229).

When I say *any*, there are some special cases, for instance:

- Exceptions thrown on close by jdbc objects shouldn't prevent business logic from being executed and shouldn't be propagated (because the failure to release resources on the database doesn't impact anything in your application), they can be logged and eaten in the method where they occur.
- InterruptedExceptions exist for flow control and need to be handled with that in mind, so that when a thread is interrupted it can respond quickly.
- SQL Exceptions generated by constraint violations caused by user actions can be caught in the controller layer and used to give the user feedback (the way [Spring identifies SQLExceptions and wraps them in exceptions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html) that reflect their cause makes it easy to handle this case).

Answer (score -3):

**catch** has to be present in a try block almost all the time except when you use **finally**. You need to use **throw** when you want to propagate the error to the caller. If you do not want to propagate the error you can **catch** it and not throw it back.

Comment: ```The question **is not** about exception handling **syntax**```