# Why can some Java exceptions be left unhandled?

Tags: java, exception

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("foobar"); 
    file.createNewFile();

    String baz = "baz";     
    int myInt = Integer.parseInt(baz);
}
```

In this code the IDE or compiler would complain that there is an unhandled exception thrown by createNewFile() and we would need to catch it to allow the code to compile.

However parseInt() also throws an exception, NumberFormatException, but we are not required to catch it, though it seems that it would be a good idea. Why are we not required to catch that exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is that exceptions which extends `RuntimeException` do not need to be caught.

`NumberFormatException` extends `IllegalArgumentException` which extends `RuntimeException`.

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) :

> Runtime exceptions can occur anywhere in a program, and in a typical one they can be very numerous. Having to add runtime exceptions in every method declaration would reduce a program's clarity. Thus, the compiler does not require that you catch or specify runtime exceptions (although you can).

Answer (score 3):

*Everything* gets handled eventually. If you don't catch it then when the exception escapes the main method the JVM will catch it and write it to stderr.

Some exceptions, like NullPointerExceptions and NumberFormatExceptions, are unchecked, which means the programmer isn't required to catch them. You couldn't require every possible NullPointerException to get caught, and adding them to method signatures would be pointless.

Like the NullPointerException, the NumberFormatException is the result of a programmer error, it means you made a bad assumption about your input to the parse method. In some cases it isn't clear why some exceptions are checked and others aren't.

Exceptions that are unchecked tend to be unrecoverable. They may indicate some external resource went down or they may indicate a programmer error; something went so wrong there's no point proceeding, the best thing to do is cancel the current work, fall back to a safe spot, and regroup. [Here's an explanation of a rationale for how to handle exceptions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25811675/217324)

Comment: Nathan, thanks for a great answer I am sorry I cannot choose more than one. You mention NullPointerException and I can see that if we had to catch every possible one it would, as Amaud quotes, "reduce the program's clarity".