# Is it better to use try/catch or throw in java?

Tags: java, exception

I am not sure when it is the proper time to use try/catch vs throw exception. Most of the time when i  use try/catch I usually just print a message and print the stack trace.

```
try {
   //try to do something
}catch(Exception e) {
   logger.error("error in doing this!");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am not sure if this is a good way to handle the exception. Is it better to just throw the exception because I don't really know how to handle it. When is it best to use try/catch and when it best to use throw?

What is the best practice for exception handling? Is it bad throwing the exception to the user for them to handle it?

Please provide some specific examples on when I should use what, and how it should be done.

P.S: I know there are some similar questions asked already, but I don't feel like the answer is adequate enough, so I would like to reask hoping for more specific examples/details.

Comment: If you can’t handle the error usefully, don’t catch it in the first place.

Comment: I guess I don't know what is consider useful. is me print a message out and printing the stack trace out consider useful?

Comment: Useful for whom?  An exception is thrown to indicate that the executing method cannot complete normally.  This may, in turn, case the method that calls the failing method to be unable to complete.  Or this method may know what to do at that point, and can `catch` the exception and proceed to return normally.  In your example, you are *suppressing* an exception - essentially saying "this failure should never cause my method to fail".  Generally speaking, you should avoid suppressing exceptions unless you really mean to; just let the exception propagate higher if you can't recover from it.

Comment: It's also pretty strange that you're logging a message then printing the stack trace.  Most logging frameworks let you log `Throwables` and will write the stack trace to the log.

Comment: i think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25811675/217324) should be specific enough.

Comment: Great! Thanks guys! sorry for the repitive question.